# How can I run a dynamo wire from my front hub to my dynamo light?

Tags: lighting

I have a Pashley Roadster Sovereign, and wanted to upgrade the dynamo driven headlight. Sadly, I didn't successfully use the old wire to pull the new wire through the front fork, and now I need to fish a wire through the fork without the aid of something to pull it through. Any tips for accomplishing this? When I try to fish the wire down the fork, it catches on something and I've never successfully located the end of the wire through the vent hole.

Comment: If you can't get the wire through the fork, that's not a problem.  Fasten the wire to the fork and stem with cable ties and leave enough slack where it "jumps" around the headset to allow full motion of the bars.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to do this by taping the end of the wire so it extends about 1/2" past the end of a bent-straight coat hanger. Using this, I was able to get the tip of the wire near the bottom vent hole, and wiggle it around enough that I could locate the wire ends. Then it was a bit of work to catch the wire and pull it through with fine needle-nose pliers, but I was able to get it twice within a minute or so after burning nearly an hour trying to fish it through using other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use a vacuum cleaner and feed a piece of cotton or light thread through, with the vacuum sucking it out the other hole. Once you've got that through, you can pull the wire through, or possibly a stronger thread/cord/line first.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I just made a spiral with the wire around the fork.